# How to know which version of an image a container is running?

Tags: docker

Suppose I have one running container:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND   CREATED       STATUS       PORTS                  NAMES
59f00e5c96d6   me/myapp:latest  "bash"    9 hours ago   Up 7 hours   127.0.0.1:80->80/tcp   bashapp
```

Suppose I found a mysterious docker image archive file `me-myapp-latest.tar.gz` out of nowhere. I want to know, relative to the image used to start the running container, whether that file contains an older or newer version of the image.

I load the archive into docker using `docker load --input me-myapp-latest.tar.gz`. `docker images` now shows:

```
REPOSITORY   TAG      IMAGE ID        CREATED           SIZE
me/myapp     latest   fe22fc800843    12 hours ago      123MB
```

This gives no indication of whether or not the `me/myapp:latest` shown by `docker images` is the same as that shown by `docker ps -a`. They are both named `me/myapp:latest`, but they could be different.

How can I determine if the images are the same, or if they're not the same, which one is newer and which is older?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can check if the imageId of your container matches the one of your image:

```
docker inspect -f '{{ .Image }}' bashapp
```

As you won't be able to remove an image that is still used, you should be able to find the image of your container with the following command:

```
docker images | grep $(docker inspect -f '{{ .Image }}' bashapp | cut -d ":" -f 2 | head -c 12)
```

If you know which image is used, you should also be able to tell whether the image is newer or not.